# EditText Views not showing up on Android API 23

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, landscape

I am fairly new to android, so apologies if this is a simple fix..

I have recently upgraded my AVD to **API 23**, and have noticed some odd changes to my application, unfortunately rendering it useless.

In short, both the buttons on my landing screen, and `EditText` views on my registration screen have disappeared. I have not changed any code, only upgraded the API. When I test the app on my Samsung Galaxy S3, the app still looks and behaves as expected.

Below is a screenshot on what my `EditText` fields are looking like after the update:

[image: As you can see, there should be EditText views between each textview, however there are not]

and Here is my layout file for the registration activity:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="coursematch.coursematch.Classes.RegisterActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Back"
    android:id="@+id/backButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="backToLanding"/>

<TextView
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/welcomeNameTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:shadowColor="#111111" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcomeNameTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.17" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.17"
        android:src="@drawable/mortarboardone" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.17" />

    <TextView
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="First Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="0.07" />

    <EditText
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/firstNameTextField" />

    <TextView
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Last Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_weight="0.17"
        android:shadowColor="#000000" />

    <EditText
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lastNameTextField"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Username (Must be unique, eg JoeBloggsQESchool)"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/usernameTextField"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Email"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/emailTextField" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Set Password"
        android:id="@+id/textView6" />

    <EditText
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/passwordTextField" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Confirm Password"
        android:id="@+id/textView7" />

    <EditText
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordTextField" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Passwords must be over 8 characters long, and     contain at least one of the following:"
        android:id="@+id/textView8" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="- Upper Case Letter"
        android:id="@+id/textView9" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="- Lower Case Letter"
        android:id="@+id/textView10" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="- Number OR Symbol"
        android:id="@+id/textView11" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Eg: FidoTheDog1"
        android:id="@+id/textView12" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="toNextTier"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/regErrorView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any help as to why this is happening would be hugely appreciated, and once again apologies if it is a trivial matter.

Thanks

Comment: change the `textColor` . sometimes, if manufacturers update the android system to the next level, they also change the default settings like textcolor of a view. I stumpled over this long time ago...in this case, it´s possible that the color has just went to black...

Comment: Which appTheme are you using?

Comment: @Shaishav AppTheme.NoActionBar

Comment: What is the parent theme?

Comment: @Shaishav Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: Everything looks Ok. Can you share your `build.gradle`, so I can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Shaishav sure: http://pastebin.com/UugBVu7Z

Comment: @Shaishav ps - thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

My Friend,

Sometimes this **fillViewport** gives problems ( though it is fundamentally their to fill the whole viewport).. thus you can safely remove from **ScrollView** tag..

I had this problem once where my app was working fine under lollipop but not good in mashmallow